# Connect Client to 4store (Protégé/Gephi/etc.)

Tags: rdf, triplestore, 4store

What is the right configuration to connect a RDF/SPARQL client like Protégé (protege.stanford.edu) or Gephi (http://gephi.github.io/, Semantic Web Import Plugin) with the tripplestore "4store"? (http://4store.org/trac/wiki/SparqlServer)?

Error in the log of Semantic Web Import Plugin: 
fr.inria.edelweiss.sparql.RdfParser$1 fatalError
SCHWERWIEGEND: Premature end of file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with 4Store but it has a sparql endpoint 
http://localhost:8000/sparql/
which can be used both by Protege/Gephi